# How to use a dll file in java code using JNA?

Tags: java, c, eclipse, exception, dll

I have to use a dll file (of c code) in my java code, for which I searched allot and found that JNA is the most suitable way for it. Therefore, I am trying to write a HelloWorld program using jna-4.1.0.jar. Below is the c code:

```
//C hello world example
#include <stdio.h>

void __declspec(dllexport) _stdcall helloFromC()
{
  printf("Hello world from the c code! \n");
}
```

and I make dll for this c code by using the following commands on cmd:

```
gcc -c ctest.c
gcc -shared -0 test.dll ctest.o
```

running these commands gives me a dll for the c code, which I place at the root of my simple java project.

Now here is my java class:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Library;

public class HelloWorld {

public interface CTest extends Library {
    void helloFromC();
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        CTest INSTANCE = (CTest) Native.loadLibrary("ctest", CTest.class);

        INSTANCE.helloFromC();
    }
}
```

Now when I run this java program on eclipse, I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Kindly help me to solve this issue as it has already taken much of time!

Comment: No, I mean JNA, using jna-4.1.0.jar

Comment: What platform/OS do you use ? to create the dll and to run java ?

Comment: It's Windows 8.1 (64-bit) and using eclipse for java

Comment: So you use this command `gcc -shared -0 test.dll ctest.o` on windows 8.1?

Comment: No, sorry its error above, actual is here:
gcc -shared -o test.dll ctest.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gcc -c ctest.c
gcc -shared -o test.dll ctest.o
try     'o'  ^  not '0'
```

It's finding your dll but it doesn't like it.

Comment: Yes I am already entering o (not 0), but I don't know why is it not accepting my dll? :(

Comment: It definitely sounds like something that windows is unable to load. Maybe install another 64 compiler and give it a try.

Comment: should I install Netbeans 64-bit?

Comment: No, I think your java application is just fine. Focus on building your .dll

Comment: Yes finally done, here are the steps that I followed (could be helpful for others)
1. Downloaded MinGW 64-bit and opened its batch file. 2. Then compiled c code here and generated a 64-bit dll file :) This worked :)